# Calling Access Report from VS 2013 Express Throws ActiveX Error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a VS 2013 Express system that uses an Access db.  After populating the db with values, I open a report object created in Access.  This all worked perfectly approximately 1 year ago.  Now, in development or production, trying to open the report throws an error.

The code behind the form is:

```
Imports Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access

Public Class frmReports

    Public db_path As String

    Dim oAccess As Access.application
```

And the code behind the button that opens the report is:

```
Private Sub btnSumByPlan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSumByPlan.Click

    oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    oAccess.visible = True
    oAccess.opencurrentdatabase(db_path)
    oAccess.docmd.openreport(ReportName:="rptSumByPlan", view:=Access.AcView.acViewPreview)

End Sub
```

However the code fails on the CreateObject line with the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.
>
> Additional information:  Cannot create ActiveX component.

I have the following COM references selected:

- Microsoft Access 12.0 Object Library
- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library
- Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3

I have tried selecting different versions of the Access, Office and ActiveX libraries but still get the same error.

I'm not positive, but I think I was running Office 2010 a year ago and now Office 2013.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Additionally, when I upgraded to Office 2013, I installed the 64-Bit version.  Could that be the issue?